# OpenJPA Reverse Mapping Tool - how to make foreign key primitive?

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, openjpa

Currently the OpenJPA reverse mapping tool generates the foreign key for entities as object types. Is there a way to make them primitive types?

Comment: Consider that primitive types are not nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you persist a new entity, it inserts '0' in place of an uninitialized primitive type (which is in line with Java initialization defaults for primitives). It would have to be the same with foreign keys, which means OpenJPA would have to generate invalid foreign keys (with "0" id, which is perfectly valid id from DB's point of view).

So, there's only the option:

```
-nullableAsObject/-no <true/t | false/f>:
By default, all non-foreign key columns are mapped to primitives
```

but, as noted, it's valid for non-FKs only.

Comment: I think the reason it doesn't allow foreign key to be primitives is because there is no possibility of object traversal without an object.